# PHP can't echo HTML <font color> within an <input value" ">

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP function as a value in my input and it gives me the PHP variable with out a problem. The problem is when I try to change the color to red when I want to echo error message (inside the input as a value). It shows  or  as plain text and shows the variable correctly.

```
<input name="name" type="text"  class="texto10" style="width:309px;border:0;" value="<?php pholder($name);?>"/>
```

And

```
function pholder($inputName) {
    global $nameErr, $name;
    if(empty($inputName)){
        echo "<span class='pholder'>".$nameErr."</span>"; 
    }else{
        echo $name;
    }
```

I've also tried

```
echo "<font color='red'>$nameErr</font>";
```

Simple quotes or double, concatenating or not, span or font etc...

$nameErr or $name is displayd OK but HTML is shown in plain text instead of changing the color.

Hope it made sense and Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to check if a name exists; if so do A, if not do B.  Test if the name exists before you create the html.  Generate the html using php since you're using it anyway.

```
function pholderExists($inputName) {
if(empty($inputName)){ return 0; }
       else { return 1; }
  }


if (pholderExists($name))
   { echo '<input name="name" type="text"  class="texto10" '.
          'style="width:309px;border:0;" value=" '.$name.' "/>'; }
 else { echo // whatever you want to do on error
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The text in an input field cannot contain different formats. And you cannot use html within the value of an input. You can change the appearance of all the text in an input field by using CSS to style the input, though.

Comment: Thanks, sooo what I was trying to do is not possible, right? With css I can do it, I was just playing around with PHP. Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use change color directives in "value" attribute.
You need to do:

```
<input style="color: red;">
```

or using directly CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In between `"..."` or `'...'` you are expected to insert literals, not HTML tags.

You are not allowed to inject HTML tags as a value of an attribute in another tag.

HTML tags are only allowed to *Nest each other* or *Reside as siblings*. No other way is accepted.